# How do I display different characters when an array is printed? (C language)

Tags: c, game-engine

Right now my array prints as follows:

```
  0 | 1 | 2 
 -----------
  3 | 4 | 5
 -----------
  6 | 7 | 8
```

I would like to to be empty, but not sure how to pull that out of my code. I want the board to look like this:

```
    |   |  
 -----------
    |   | 
 -----------
    |   |
```

Not really sure why I can't figure out how to get this to work. Any quick help?

Comment: Try commenting out `if(board[i] == ' ') printf(" %i ",i);` (and the `else` that follows it, but not its body) in `displayBoard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the initial case you were printing the index, you don't have to do that and your sizeof doesn't work... so it becomes :-

```
void displayBoard(char board[]){
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    printf(" %c ",board[i]);
    if(i != 2 && i != 5 && i != 8) printf("|");
    if(i == 2 || i == 5) printf("\n------------\n");
}
printf("\n");
}
```

with your original,  `sizeof(board)`  it is equal to 4

because its a parameter to the function, and is a pointer.

BONUS ANSWER: providing a keyboard mapping

```
int keyboard_mapping[9] = {6,7,8,3,4,5,0,1,2};
int from_entry(char* s)
{
    int v = atoi(s);
    if(v < 1 || v > 9) return 0; // we have a problem...not handled
    return keyboard_mapping[v-1];
}
```

then things like :-

```
board[atoi(move)] = 'X';
```

become

```
board[from_entry(move)] = 'X';
```

MORE BONUS:

set first to 1 or 2 depending if you want the player to go first or second.

```
char move[] = "";
    int turn;
    int first;

    //TODO ask the user whether to do go first or second
    printf("Tic-Tac-Toe\nCreated by \nYou are first! What's your move going to be?\n");
    while(checkForWin(board) == ' ' && boardFull(board) == 0){
        printf("\n");
        displayBoard(board);
        for(turn=1; turn <= 2; turn++;)
        {
            if(turn == first)
            {
                printf("\nSelection a position to place your piece: ");
                scanf("%s",move);
                if(board[atoi(move)] == ' ')
                {
                    board[atoi(move)] = 'X';
                }               
            }
            else
            {
                int compmove = chooseMove(board, 1).move;
                board[compmove] = 'O';
            }        
        }
        else {
            printf("\n----------------------------------------\n\nPlease choose another location.\nThis one has already been selected.\n\n----------------------------------------\n\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is a good start. By doing that, the formatting of the board went away. Is there a way to add the spaces necessary like my example up top of what I wanted it to look like?

Comment: I changed the for loop, and it prints out like you wanted on mine

Comment: just for your understanding, in that function char board[] is being passed in, that is a pointer, and the pointer size is 4  and the sizeof a board entry is 1.

Comment: Would there be a way to change the button input? For example, turn:
0=7, 1=8, 2=9, 3=4, 4=5, 5=6, 6=1, 7=2, 8=3

Comment: not quite sure I'm following about what you mean by "button input"?

Comment: The player inputs a number. Where their "X" goes depends on the number they press. Right now, the top row is 0-1-2, second row is 3-4-5. and the third row is 6-7-8. I wanted it to be a little easier for the user and match the input commands to the number pad on the right of a keyboard. For example: 7-8-9. 4-5-6. 1-2-3

Comment: Sweet. You sure seem to know your stuff! I was just thinking, would it be easy to implement a function that would allow the player to choose if they wanted the first move or the second move? How much code would have to be changed for that?

Comment: Also, when I added your code in, I put it right above the best chooseMove function. When I selected a key to press, the program crashed. Did I put it in the wrong spot?

Comment: The code you are providing makes sense to me, but when I add it into my code it errors. Both the number mapping and the selection of first or second move. Trying to go through them now to see what the issue is.

Comment: not sure how your code looks now....  just checked the code compiles and works for the "from_entry" function,  seems to work ok for me

Comment: The code compiles fine, you are correct there. It is just that when the user goes to input a position to place their piece, the game crashes then.

Comment: I mean, if I test the code passing in strings, I get indexes out that make sense.  So the function seems to work ok, I'm just not sure how you've put it into your code

Comment: Interesting. Where are you placing that function in the code? Like before which function

Comment: this is getting a bit outside stackoverflow.... go to my user profile and email me :)

Answer (score 1):

In your displayBoard function you are printing out the numbers on the board if the board array has a space in that slot.  If you really want to always print nothing in the board: change it to this:

```
void displayBoard(char board[]){
    for(int i=0;i<=(sizeof(board)/sizeof(board[0]));i++){
        //if(board[i] == ' ') printf(" %i ",i);
        //else printf(" %c ",board[i]);
        if(i != 2 && i != 5 && i != 8) printf("|");
        if(i == 2 || i == 5) printf("\n------------\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The real question is what are you trying to accomplish with this code (that I assume you didn't write?)

Comment: You may want to leave the body of that `else` uncommented, otherwise the `'X'`s and `'O'`s aren't going to get printed.